# NGINX as reverse proxy on another container - how to configure the config files

Tags: docker

I want to have Nginx reverse proxy in front of another container. Both these containers will be on the same docker network using:

```
docker network create my-net
```

Now, normally I can then inspect to see what IP the container is on and then use this in the Nginx config file. How do I do this so it is seamless? So that I can use a single docker-compose file and have both containers on the same network and have the Nginx configured correctly.

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use docker-compose you don't need to create your own network, it will create a private network that is aware of all the other services in the same compose file. For example:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  php:
    image: php5.6
    ...<snip>...
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
     - "443:443"
    links:
     - php
    ...<snip>...
```

then in nginx config:

```
proxy_pass  http://php;
```

You shouldn't need to specify the "links" for networking in the nginx compose block (it should be aware of all the service names), however it will help to define the load order of the containers.

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each
>   container for a service joins the default network and is both
>   reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by
>   them at a hostname identical to the container name.
>
> > https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: thanks! I am guessing that this is using the inbuilt dns resolver that ships with Engine - that is how you can specify just http://php; in the nginx.conf?

Comment: Basically, yes. See link added above.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend use [Automated Nginx reverse proxy for docker containers](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/)

> nginx-proxy sets up a container running nginx and docker-gen. docker-gen generates reverse proxy configs for nginx and reloads nginx when containers are started and stopped.